# Session timeout if the user is idle for certain time

Tags: javascript, session, timeout

Hi I am logging out the user if the user is idle for 1 minute and I am trying to extend the session time out onkeypress,onmousemove,onmosueout etc. session time out is happening but the extending the session time out on above events is not happening.Please help me in this regard.
My code :

```
var InactivityTime = function () {
    var t;
    window.onload = resetTimer();
    document.onmousemove = resetTimer();
    document.onkeypress = resetTimer();
    document.onmousedown = resetTimer();
    document.onmouseclick= resetTimer();
    document.onmouseup=resetTimer();

    function logout() {
        alert("Your session has been expired.Please Re-Login to continue");      
    }

    function resetTimer() {
        clearTimeout(t);
        t = setTimeout(logout, 60000);

        // 1000 milisec = 1 sec
    }
    return {
        //main function to initiate the module
        init: function () {           
            resetTimer();            
        }   
    };
}();
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to register the event listeners in the init function as below:

```
return {
    //main function to initiate the module
    init: function () {           
        resetTimer();
        window.onload = resetTimer();
        document.onmousemove = resetTimer();
        document.onkeypress = resetTimer();
        document.onmousedown = resetTimer();
        document.onmouseclick= resetTimer();
        document.onmouseup=resetTimer();
    }
};
```

Also those event listeners seem to be redundant. I would reduce them down to keypress and mousemove only.

And a good way to debug is to add a console.log() statement in the resetTimer() function:

```
function resetTimer() {
    clearTimeout(t);
    t = setTimeout(logout, 60000);
    console.log("reset");
    // 1000 milisec = 1 sec
}
```

Comment: have you tried it with the console.log() message added?

Answer (score 0):

```
function InactivityTimer(path, delay) {

  // private instance var
  var timeout;

  // private functions
  function logout() {
    alert("you've been logged out");
    window.location.href = path || "/";
  }

  function reset() {
    stop();
    start();
  }

  function start() {
    if (!timeout) {
      timeout = setTimeout(logout, delay || 60000);
    }
  }

  function stop() {
    if (timeout) {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = null;
    }
  }

  // export public api
  this.start = start;
  this.stop  = stop;
  this.reset = reset;

  // init
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", reset);
  document.addEventListener("keypress",  reset);
}
```

Now you can use it like this

```
var timer = new InactivityTimer("/logout", 60000);

// maybe some other event stops the timer?
timer.stop();

// something else starts it back up
timer.start();
```